# Run NodeJS server from AWS EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

EC2 is properly deployed with my NodeJS server but I can't figure out how to keep it running without an ssh connection to the linux machine and running `npm start`

For Example:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-89-105 me_server]$ npm start

> me-server@1.0.0 start
> nodemon index.js

[nodemon] 2.0.20
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Server Started at 8080
Database Connected
```

I can run this command from an ssh tunnel from my local machine but I don't want my local machine to be in control of the server connection, how can I tell EC2 to run `npm start` on its own and keep it running indefinitely?

Comment: write a systemd service

Comment: Process Manager 2 (PM2) pm2 start appname.js --name "appname#1"

Comment: You may then perform a pm2 startup and pm2 save and have it deploy on reboot your list of processes to auto run.